# UML plugin for Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, uml

I am looking for a good UML plugin for Netbeans 7.3 for SE and EE Java Development. The plugin should be able to create UML from code, generate code from UML, keep the code and the UML diagrams synchronized. If it can give any additional design facility, it would be welcome. Kindly give suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There WAS a UML plugin for Netbeans till 6th version. But starting from 7, the only UML plugin for Netbeans is PlantUML. It supports drawing some UML diagramms only, no modelling, no code engineering and its ways are far from UML standard.

The old plugin AFAIK was supported by Visual Paradigm. Now it is stopped. You can see ALL Netbeans *plugins* on [their site](http://plugins.netbeans.org/).

VP UML product has several licenses. The lowest one for a modelling and not-engineering for free and The middle one for $200 supports code and back engineering. And it can connect to Netbeans and be up to the code.